# IE9: store.find promise isn't resolved

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've got something like the following code (coffeescript):

```
Ember.Application.initializer
  name: 'currentPerson'
  initialize: (container, application) ->
    application.deferReadiness()
    store.find('person', 'current')
    .then (person) ->
      #Never executed
      application.advanceReadiness()
    .fail >
      #Never executed
      application.advanceReadiness()
```

This works in all other browsers, but not in IE9.

The funny thing is, if I debug this, and put a breakpoint just after findById creates the promise (findById is called by store.find), it works. So it seems like a data race of some sort. Have anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

It is surprising to me it works in all other browsers, because I think you'd have to use a fat arrow (`=>`) to access `application`, and besides that you are never calling advanceReadiness (needs `()`).

If an error occurs in any of the then/fail methods, it will fail silently. To catch these errors, see https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js#error-handling.

Comment: Sorry, the code was written from the top of my head, and I write alot of Ruby, so the code might not be entirely correct, I'll fix that immidietly. I know that the "then" and "fail" functions aren't called because I've set breakpoints in them, so no exceptions have the chance to occur.

Comment: And no, you don't need the fat arrow unless you plan to use 'this' without refering to the current function.